# Blender 2.80: Buttons' tooltip do not show Python function anymore

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I started picking up scripting in `Blender 2.79` and what I love is how every button shows the Python function code, which makes the learning like speed of light.
However, this is not the case anymore in Blender 2.80. I understand for usability reason they might have taken that out. But is it possible to enable this nice feature again because I believe there are many changes in 2.80 in from scripting perspective.

Also, it would be good if someone can point me to a good resource to learn Blender scripting for beginner?

Comment: You can toggle it in the UI user preferences just like you did in 2.79. Blender 2.8 is not ready yet, these things are bound to change until release so this question is off topic for now

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it about unfinished features on experimental development software

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos do you want to convert your comment to answer or should i close this question? anyway, based on your tip i found the way to reopen it.